# Expressing the Domain of a Function Correctly

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

Say we have the function $y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-3}}$ and we are asked to find the domain.

So basically the function will be undefined when $x = 0$, and is between  $-\sqrt{3}$ and $0$ and also, $0$ and $\sqrt{3}$. What would be the best way to express the function's domain?

Could you say something like,

$x:x\neq(-\sqrt{3}, 0 ] $ $\cup$  $[0, \sqrt{3})$

Or is that not mathematically correct?

Answer (score 2):

I feel this is simpler
$$x \in (-\infty, -\sqrt{3}) \cup (\sqrt{3}, \infty)$$

$$f(x) : (-\infty, -\sqrt{3}) \cup (\sqrt{3}, \infty) \to (0, \infty)$$